# Should I worry about sql injection in the case of SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql

If I only run a SELECT query, should I worry about sql injection?  My site has only a few input fields, and all they do is look up information. I never delete, update, etc...

Comment: Yes: [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: if you use user-supplied data **ANYWHERE** in a query, you are vulnerable to injection attacks. And by "user-supplied", I mean ANY outside data - you can easily inject yourself as well.

Comment: users are bad people all of them!

Comment: @Barmar this comic is great! haha

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what kind of query you're trying to do. The SQL injection can end your query and start another one, which could be a DELETE, UPDATE, or INSERT. This is the lesson of [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to worry. It doesn't matter what queries do you execute inside PHP or whatever script you use. An evil user can submit something like `"; DROP DATABASE` and you'll be sorry for that.

Comment: @Pinoniq yep, no idea what the author of the comment meant by that

Comment: That is very interesting. Your answer explains it well. What if I set permissions to the user in the PHP script to only be able to do Select statements? Then am I safe? I'm assuming mYSQL will deny and other commands at that point. I'd rather just restrict permissions and not change all my scripts

Comment: @Pinoniq php can only exec 1 statement per call to the database. Thats not to say its safe, its still exploitable by unions etc but the example of "; DROP DATABASE" will not work in PHP

Comment: @DaveFes PHP script permissions are something different than MySQL permissions. You can `GRANT PERMISSIONS` inside MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html). But still, this doesn't make your application safe. Use functions like `mysql_real_escape_string` instead.

Comment: @user1281385 I strongly disagree with that. This has nothing to do with PHP, python, ruby or whatever. If a user can submit anything via form, the app has to analyse the inut before sending it to the database. And PHP has nothing to do here.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz the documentation reads "sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)" SQL injection yes, That exact example - in  php - then no

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should. SQL injection doesn't have nothing to do on what is the original query about. It can inject any command of any clause on your query.

On PHP is really simple to make your site/system/project protected.

Take a look on this [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) with examples of this tecnique and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), how to avoid it, using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

UPDATE: I have used it once using this `' or 1=1 or ''='` on both username and password fields of a login page. It results on a query like this `select * from user where username = '' or 1=1 or ''='' and password = '' or 1=1 or ''=''` and may return a record.

See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ed6b/1) of how it works.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to `SELECT` based on the user's input, then you do have to worry about it, since the user can put anything on the input field.

Comment: -1. you have to worry about it on **ANY** query where you include external data in the query string, not just selects.

Comment: They can still inject a union for example and get access to data not meant for them